# Is it normal for my IPv6 to change?

Tags: network, ip, logging

My IPv6 is changing a lot, exactly three times in last three days (I saw on Microsoft's last activity), and all accounts that I keep login on my browser have disconnected. The actual IP is listed by Google as a IP from a nearby neighborhood. Is this normal? May I be worried?

Comment: Do you expect static IP address? Is your ISP charging extra for a static IPv6?

Comment: I assume you are asking in a context of home internet service provider and in this case you probably received a dynamic IP address that ISP forces to change daily due to some business reasons. I suggest to ask directly your ISP technical helpline about this. Again I assume some ISPs are charging extra for static "business" IP addresses that are permanent once set.

Comment: Yes, it is a home context. I look in my modem settings and I saw that IP's route changed, but in the past and now the IP is from my IPS. So, is this normal, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My IPv6 is changing a lot, exactly three times in last three days

You most likely have a dynamic IP address. These are often used because it makes managing IP addresses easier for an ISP. Some ISPs will charge extra for a static address which does not change. This is common for businesses or customers who wish to host a website over their connection.

> all accounts that I keep login on my browser have disconnected

Many websites will automatically log you out if your IP address changes for security reasons. This is normal behavior and is to be expected when using a connection with a dynamic IP assigned.

> The actual IP is listed by Google as a IP from a nearby neighborhood.

It is possible to geolocate IP addresses, but the accuracy can vary considerably. Sometimes it's accurate to within a few miles, but other times it doesn't even get the city right. Occasionally, the entire country is wrong. If your home IP address is showing an incorrect location, this is normal.

> Is this normal? May I be worried?

This is completely normal and there is nothing to be worried about. If these frequent IP changes are causing you trouble, you may want to contact your ISP and inquire about upgrading to a static address.